# is partial derivative holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, holomorphic-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. If $z = x + \Bbb i y$, are the partial derivatives $\dfrac {\partial ^{k+l} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l}$ holomorphic functions themselves?

---

My idea: Proof by induction

$k=1: \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is real differentiable. But why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ complex differentiable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a function $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that is only once $\mathbb C$-differentiable.

Comment: yes you are right. Lets say f is holomorphic. Are we allowed to say that ( del f/del x )is complex differentiable ?

Comment: $\partial f/\partial x = f'$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @ThomasMuller: I have reformulated your question in the hope that I have correctly understood what you ask. If I was wrong, do not hesitate to roll back to the previous version of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the partial derivatives of $f$ are themselves holomorphic, and this is easily shown using [the Cauchy-Riemann relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Conformal_mappings). We want to prove that $\Bbb i \dfrac \partial {\partial x} \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l} = \dfrac \partial {\partial y} \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l}$, knowing that $\Bbb i \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial x} = \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial y}$. Using the symmetry of the higher-order partial derivatives we may write

$$\Bbb i \dfrac \partial {\partial x} \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l} = \Bbb i \dfrac {\partial ^{k+1+l} f} {\partial x^{k+1} \partial y ^l} = \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l}} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l} \Bbb i \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial x} = \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l}} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l} \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial y} = \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l+1} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^{l+1}} = \dfrac \partial {\partial y} \dfrac {\partial ^{k+l} f} {\partial x^k \partial y ^l}$$

which is exactly what we want to get.